# Connect the SMS Send Log to the SMSMessageTracking Data View

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

The SMSJobID in the send log is a GUID, not the normal numerical identifier like the SendJobID that is inside SMSMessageTracking DV.

SMS Send Log:
[image]

SMS Message Tracking:
[image]

I have tried looking to see if there is some pattern in the GUID that it included the numeric JobID - but no luck. I have compared the GUID across all other data points in the DV and no luck either.

Then I started adding in any personalization strings I could think of (hoping to find something undocumented) and nothing worked. jobid always returns 0 - which is kinda expected as it says in the description it is only for email.

I feel like I am in crazy town that the Job ID for the same job would not only be different values, but also completely different data types.

The closest I have found so far is to match on MobileNumber, SubscriberID and a soft match on sendDate. Not exactly reliable, especially if there are multiple sends at the same time (e.g. Transactional messaging).

Comment: there isn't going to be a way to match smsjobid to sendid/sendjobid  and it appears that this can be NULL more often than populated (API/JB/OUTBOUND all NULL)  You could also match on mobilemessageid to give a better soft match possibly. Can you add col to send log to capture the data you are looking for from the dataview?

Comment: The issue is that I want to match message to message, which usually can be accomplished by Job/Batch/SubID or similar. I have no way to do that here outside of reports as no matter what column I add to the send log, it wouldn't translate to either DV (unless there are other personalization strings I am unaware of). I am honestly kinda confused on the whole point of the send log and the DV if they only connect each other with soft relationships at best...

Comment: @EazyE - if you want to post your comment as an answer I will award the bounty so it doesn't go to waste and your comment is essentially what I got from everyone I asked in SF, so currently is really the only 'answer' there is.

Comment: More info: [Description of the fields in _SMSMessageTracking dataview that return NULL values](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000355536&type=1)

Comment: Related to JB SMS: [JBActivityID and JBDefinitionID fields on SMSMessageTracking Data View Not Populating](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000363384&type=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that currently there is no way to accomplish this and there is no existing effort on SFMC end to correct this.  The best you can do is soft matches on data and leave open the risk of potential data corruption due to mismatched records.

I created an '[idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003fPGQAY)' in the Trailblazer community - please add support to this and hopefully we can get some movement to resolve this issue.

Comment: You got my vote ;)

Answer (score 3):

There isn't going to be a way to match smsjobid to sendid/sendjobid as this appears these fields can be NULL more often than populated (API/JB/OUTBOUND sends are all NULL)

Answer (score 2):

Recently we have introduced 2 new columns into SMSMessageTracking data view (SMSJobID and SMSBatchID) those can be used to join SMS Sendlog. Please check and let us know if you face any issue. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_rn_2023_spring_sms_id_values.htm&type=5